# How to debug Azure Webjob written on Java

Tags: java, azure, intellij-idea, remote-debugging, azure-webjobs

Is it possible to debug Azure Webjob which is written on Java? What configuration should be used? I only found examples how to debug .NET webjobs using Visual Studio. It would be great to do the same for Java with Intellij IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

For now, the Remote Debugging function only support visual studio, and there is not any official tool to remote debug azure app service with Eclipse or Idea.

Furthermore, if you make sure your webjob jar file is runnable ,configure it with batch file correctly, then there is no need to remote debug.

If you insist on the remote debugging, you could refer to this tool [**azure-websites-java-remote-debugging**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-websites-java-remote-debugging). However when I test it , I got the same problem as the **Error communicating with remote** mentioned in the **Issues**. Maybe you could have a try.

If you still have other questions, please let me know.